# How to parse key's values from xml.data's parsed input

Tags: xml, clojure

I am having trouble figuring out what the elements are in parsed xml input, after I extract values using the :content key. Given the following parsed xml input, how can I extract the values for all the :content keys?

> ```
> #clojure.data.xml.Element{
>   :tag :Header, 
>   :attrs {}, 
>   :content (
>       #clojure.data.xml.Element{
>           :tag :ExportType, 
>           :attrs {}, 
>           :content ("Tamper Export")} 
>       #clojure.data.xml.Element{
>           :tag :CurrentDateTime, 
>           :attrs {}, 
>           :content ("2012-06-26T15:40:22.063")} 
>       #clojure.data.xml.Element{
>           :tag :ScheduledDateTime, 
>           :attrs {}, 
>           :content ("2012-06-25T00:00:00")} 
>       #clojure.data.xml.Element{
>           :tag :ExportGuid, 
>           :attrs {}, 
>           :content ("{06643D9B-DCD3-459B-86A6-D21B20A03576}")} 
>       #clojure.data.xml.Element{
>           :tag :FractionalReadIndicator, 
>           :attrs {}, 
>           :content ("1")})}
> ```

This output was created by parsing an xml file using data.xml, and then extracted using

```
(first (:content parsed-xml-input))
```

Thank you.

The following is giving me only device type and device id, which is only part of :content in the xml file. `<DeviceId>80580608</DeviceId><DeviceType>43</DeviceType>`

```
(defn extract-inner-map-val
    "Returns a map of embedded :content tag and value."

    [item]

    (let [key-elem (-> item :content first)
          val-elem (-> item :content second)]

        [(-> key-elem :content first)
         (-> val-elem :content first)]))

(defn extract-content-from-map
    "Accepts a sequence of values associated with a map key,
     and transforms them into a map of key/value pairs."

    [parsed-map]

    (into {} (map extract-inner-map-val (:content parsed-map))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this basically comes down to walking the tree and selecting all the :content. You can do this and a lot more with clojure.zip (Functional Zippers), though in this case that is a bit heavy handed when all you really need is a tree walk.

```
user> (pprint 
        (flatten 
         (map :content (first (tree-seq :content :content (:content data))))))

("Tamper Export"
 "2012-06-26T15:40:22.063"
 "2012-06-25T00:00:00"
 "{06643D9B-DCD3-459B-86A6-D21B20A03576}"
 "1")
```

You may want it willout the flatten, that just makes it print more nicely.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I had a prior solution, and I'll edit the original post to reflect using that. It's giving me part of the data.

Comment: What did you see in the data that caused you to think about a tree-seq?

Comment: I usually use zippers for parsing xml because xml is a tree of map (at least after it's parsed). In this case I just needed a simple traversal of the tree so zippers seemed overkill. In general I tend to treat anything with more than two levels of nesting as a tree.

Comment: I think that's what I've found up doing ultimately. I have what I want in each element of a sequence and use zipmap.